# Improve score if the field starts with the term

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

I'm trying to do an efficient auto-complete search input on my website, to search cities. I assume that people will always start to search their city name, with the right order of words.
E.g. a user who live in `Saint-Maur` will type `sai..` but will never type `mau..` in first place.

I need to improve the score of results, if the result starts with the term from the query. E.g. if a user type `pari`, the city `Parigné-le-Pôlin` should have a better score than `Fontenay-en-Parisis`, since it starts with `pari`.

I'm using an edge-gram filter, and a phrase match because the order of words matters. I'm sure that my problem has a simple solution, but I'm a newb in the ES magic world :)

Here is my mapping:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1
        },

        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "partialPostalCodeAnalyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["partialFilter"]
                },
                "partialNameAnalyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "word_delimiter", "partialFilter"]
                },
                "searchAnalyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "word_delimiter"]
                }
            },

            "filter": {
                "partialFilter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 50
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "mappings": {
        "village": {
            "properties": {
                "postalCode": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "partialPostalCodeAnalyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "searchAnalyzer"
                },

                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "partialNameAnalyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "searchAnalyzer"
                },

                "population": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some sample:

```
PUT /tv_village/village/1 {"name": "Paris"}
PUT /tv_village/village/2 {"name": "Parigny"}
PUT /tv_village/village/3 {"name": "Fontenay-en-Parisis"}
PUT /tv_village/village/4 {"name": "Parigné-le-Pôlin"}
```

If I perform this query, you can see that results are not in the order I want them to be (I want the 4th result to be before the 3d one):

```
GET /tv_village/village/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": "pari"
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "tv_village",
            "_type": "village",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.7768564,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Paris"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "tv_village",
            "_type": "village",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.7768564,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Parigny"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "tv_village",
            "_type": "village",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.3884282,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Fontenay-en-Parisis"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "tv_village",
            "_type": "village",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.3884282,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Parigné-le-Pôlin"
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Suggest API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)? It may be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mapping definition, put another analyzer:

```
            "keywordLowercaseAnalyer": {
              "tokenizer": "keyword",
              "filter": ["lowercase"]
            }
```

meaning, keep the word intact (through `keyword` analyzer) and lowercase it (like "parigné-le-pôlin").
Then define for your `name` field another two fields:

- one `raw` that should be `not_analyzed`
- one `raw_lowercase` that should use `keywordLowercaseAnalyer`

  ```
  "name": {
    "type": "string",
    "index_analyzer": "partialNameAnalyzer",
    "search_analyzer": "searchAnalyzer",
    "fields": {
      "raw": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "raw_lowercase": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "keywordLowercaseAnalyer"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

I'm doing this because you can have searches for "pari" or "Pari". In your query, use the `rescore` functionality to recompute the scoring based on an additional query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": "pari"
    }
  },
  "rescore": {
    "query": {
      "rescore_query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {"prefix": {"name.raw": "pari"}},
            {"prefix": {"name.raw_lowercase": "pari"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are two drawbacks, from your use case point of view and regarding `prefix` query:

- it is quite resource intensive
- the value passed to a `prefix` is `not_analyzed` and this is the reason for adding those two `raw*` fields: one field deals with a lowercase version, the other deals with the untouched version so that queries for "pari" or "Pari" cover these scenarios.

I have two suggestions:

- test the query above on your real data to see how it behaves, performance wise
- play with `window_size` attribute for `rescore` query to limit the number of values the rescoring is performed on, thus improving the performance.

For your reference, this is the [documentation page for `rescore`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-rescore.html).

Comment: Hello, thank you for this nice answer, I made some few change to adapt it to my code and everything seems to be ok now :) I only have one question : what is the purpose of the boolean in your rescore query? Is it mandatory? Regards

Comment: It was the first idea I could think of to put two "prefix" queries in the same query.